# Cursor "skip_rows" when scrolling ListView upwards...?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

I have a ListView that uses a SimpleCursorAdapter to get data from an SQLite database. The actual database file is 1049kB (that includes 6 pretty hefty TEXT columns that I don't fetch), and all the data (from the rows I'm fetching to the listview) is only 415kB in a total of 2894 rows and 31 columns.

The problem is when I'm fetching all the rows into the ListView and quickscrolling to the bottom (or at least somewhere beyond row 2000) and start scrolling up, the scrolling is very laggy and I get "Cursor: skip_rows row ####" in LogCat. It never happens when I scroll down or when I scroll up among the first 2000 rows. It also doesn't happen if I have previously displayed the rows one time.

What's going on? Obviously it's got something to do with the fact that the cursor has used up it's maximum cache size of 1MB. But first of all it shouldn't need that much memory (?) and second why does it only happen when scrolling up? Is there any way around this (besides fetching fewer columns from the database - I actually display all 30 columns in my listview)?

**LogCat**

```
02-19 21:55:37.329: E/CursorWindow(9203): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 2, freeSpace() = 1, numRows = 2347
02-19 21:55:37.329: E/CursorWindow(9203): not growing since there are already 2347 row(s), max size 1048576
02-19 21:55:37.329: E/Cursor(9203): Failed allocating 2 bytes for text/blob at 2346,26
02-19 21:55:37.349: D/Cursor(9203): finish_program_and_get_row_count row 547
02-19 21:55:37.449: D/Cursor(9203): skip_rows row 2893
02-19 21:55:37.539: D/Cursor(9203): skip_rows row 2892
02-19 21:55:38.709: D/Cursor(9203): skip_rows row 2891
02-19 21:55:38.879: D/Cursor(9203): skip_rows row 2890
```

...and so on while scrolling up into previously undisplayed rows > row ~2000...

Comment: post the code from your adapter, there may be some optimizations to do there.

Comment: the solution is easy: use custom AbstractWindowedCursor

Comment: @pskink Can you be any more specific on how I would actually do that?

Comment: instead of selecting all the rows you have to modify your select query so that it returns small "window" that will be used to fill CursorWindow which is used by AbstractWindowedCursor

Comment: @pskink Still not sure how that's done. I tried Googling it but found nothing useful. Do you have any links to point me in the right direction? Do you use the AbstractWindowedCursor with a SimpleCursorAdapter? How do you handle requerying when the user scrolls out of the "window"? And how do I obtain an AbstractWindowedCursor from my SQLiteDatabase in the first place? As you can tell I really have no idea how to do this...

Comment: docs say: "Subclasses are responsible for filling the cursor window with data during onMove(int, int) , allocating a new cursor window if necessary.
During requery() , the existing cursor window should be cleared and filled with new data." and yes you can use it with any CursoAdapter, Simple too

Comment: @njzk2 I tried it with a plain vanilla SimpleCursorAdapter and am having the same issue, so it's not related to my adapter subclass.

Comment: for more detail see sources. of SQLiteCursor.java

Comment: @pskink : I don't see anything in the code of SQLiteCursor that would suggest that it would skip rows or fail to call fillWindow.

Comment: @njzk2 neither i, probably the warnings come from native code?

Comment: @BadCash : could you post the logcat with the skip_rows exact message ? I'd like to try and find where does that come from.

Comment: @njzk2 I posted the LogCat in the original post, enjoy... :)

Comment: `numRows = 2347` and `row 2890` seems contradictory. are you changing the cursor one way or another at some point ?

Comment: @njzk2 No, my guess is that the first 2347 rows equal the magical 1MB limit. The resultset contains 2894 rows total.